Cant set variable in winform
For some reason, my variable(which holds multiple variables) in my Updateform can't be set to any value whatsoever[It keeps coming up null when it is getting sent information(I did it in multiple ways, so I am 100% sure I am sending what I need)], This is weird as I previously  set a string on the previous form I opened, Using the same method I used on this one.
Code:
//This is on the seriepage form
 private void SeriesPageUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
     Update update = new Update();
     update.UpdateBaseInformation = UpdateData;//Data taken from Controls in the seriepage form
     update.Show();
     
 }
//this is on the form that i am trying to set updatebaseinformation on
 public partial class Update : Form
 {
     public DataClass UpdateBaseInformation {  get; set; } //I want to set this to what i got from the other form just once 
     DataAccesObject accesObject = new DataAccesObject();
     public Update() 
     {
         InitializeComponent();
        
         SeriesImage.ImageLocation = UpdateBaseInformation.C_Image;
         SeriesLink.Text = UpdateBaseInformation.C_Link;
         SeriesLocation.Text = UpdateBaseInformation.C_Location;
         SeriesTitle.Text = UpdateBaseInformation.C_Title;
         SeriesRating.Text =UpdateBaseInformation.C_Rating;
         SeriesDescription.Text = UpdateBaseInformation.C_Description;
         if (UpdateBaseInformation.C_Type == "Comic")
         {
             SeriesTypeComic.Checked = true;
         }
         else if (UpdateBaseInformation.C_Type == "Show")
         {
             SeriesTypeShow.Checked = true;
         }
         else if (UpdateBaseInformation.C_Type == "Book")
         {
             SeriesTypeBook.Checked = true;
         }
         else if (UpdateBaseInformation.C_Type == "Movie")
         {
             SeriesTypeMovie.Checked = true;
         }
         string[] Temporary = accesObject.SplitTagBundle(UpdateBaseInformation.C_Tags);
         for (int i = 0; i < Temporary.Length; i++)
         {
             SeriesTag.Items.Add(Temporary[i]);
         }
     }
}

//And this is the code for setting a string in the seriepage form
 private void Mouseclicked(object sender,EventArgs e)
 {
    SeriePage page = new SeriePage();
     page.Title = ControlTitle;
     page.Show();
 }

//And this is the string getting set
public string Title { get; set; }

They are exactly the same so why is one working but not the other?
I cant find anything about this :(

The problem is that this line:
Update update = new Update();

is invoking the constructor of class Update. In this constructor you attempt to use the UpdateBaseInformation property of the class. But at this point it is still null (its initial value).
This is so because you set it only at the line after the one above:
update.UpdateBaseInformation = UpdateData;

To solve it, you can pass the UpdateData object to the constructor, and use it to initialize the UpdateBaseInformation before using it:
public partial class Update : Form
{
     public DataClass UpdateBaseInformation {  get; set; } 
     //...

     // Default constructor - keep it for the usage of Forms designner:
     public Update()
     {
         InitializeComponent();
     }

     // Constructor which accepts DataClass:
     // -----------vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv-
     public Update(DataClass updateData) : this()
     {
         // Initialize the property:
         UpdateBaseInformation = updateData;
         // Now UpdateBaseInformation will not be `null` and you can use it:
         SeriesImage.ImageLocation = UpdateBaseInformation.C_Image;
         //...
     }
     //...
}

And when you create Update pass UpdateData to the constructor:
private void SeriesPageUpdate_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     //-------------------------vvvvvvvvvv--
     Update update = new Update(UpdateData);
     update.Show();
}

Note that the default constructor is still kept available, for the usage of the Forms designer. The constructor that accepts the DataClass object is invoking it before doing the rest of the initializations.

Well just a few minutes ago,i didnt have enough points to vote you up,so I am doing that now!
